PHP session cookie deleted on phone restart but not PC restart
I have a PHP application where the PHP session cookie is set to expire after 30 days. This works fine on a PC and it survives a PC restart, but recently my users have started complaining that they have to login again after restarting their phones.  Any ideas?
I tried changing the IP address on my PC to see if that was the problem with the phone restarting, but it made no difference.

If they started complaining only recently it would be interesting to know if the OS of the phone is iOS or Android and which browser was used. What did the investigation of your logs tell you?

Restarting their phones probably clears stored cookies, even if they should be valid for longer. Sounds like a "privacy-enhancing" measure applied by the phone manufacturer / mobile browser vendor.

I've solved the problem. It turned out that the problem people were reporting was that they were being asked to log in again when going to the site, even though they had previously been logged in.
I had forgotten that I had recently set the session cookie's SameSite attribute to "Strict" and so if users were going to the site from another, different, site to the one they had used previously, the cookie wouldn't be valid.  Changing it back to "Lax" confirmed that this was the cause.
